# Changing Colours In PHP

Tags: php

The following are a couple of code snippets from some very basic PHP. I decided to add alternating row colours to make things a bit clearer. However the problem I have is that whatever I set the colour values to the rows alternate between a dark red and fuchsia background. This happens on both Windows and Linux and I cannot understand why?

```
$row_count = 1; // track rows
//$colour_odd = "#FFE680";
$colour_odd = "F0FFFF";
//$colour_even = "#FFF2BF";
$colour_even = "00FFFF";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row_colour = (($row_count % 2) == 0) ? colour_even: colour_odd;
    echo '
        <tr bgcolor="' . $row_colour . '">
            <td width="150" align="center">' . $row['FirstName'] . '</td>
            <td align="center"><a href="' . $row['LastName'] . '">' .$row['LastName'] . '</a></td>
         </tr>';
    $row_count++;
}
```

Comment: `colour_even: colour_odd` those are treated as constants. You probably forgot the `$` signs. Using error reporting would have told you something like "Undefined constant...."

Comment: `$row_colour = (($row_count % 2) == 0) ? $colour_even: $colour_odd;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting my comment to an answer:

`colour_even: colour_odd` those are treated as [**constants**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). You probably forgot the `$` signs.

Using error reporting would have told you something like "Undefined constant colour_even..." *etc.*

Modify it to read as: `$colour_even: $colour_odd;`

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Well spotted. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for the error reporting - the IDE did not suggest there was an issue!

Answer (score 3):

Although you can do it in PHP and you've tagged your question with PHP, I much prefer using CSS with the nth selector.

For example, have the following CSS rules,

```
tr {
   background: #00FFFF;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+2) {
    background: #F0FFFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9msus8ka/

Answer (score 1):

This is all so wrong. Please stop using whatever sources you're studying, and start reading [PHP, The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/)

First, please use PDO or MySQLi to connect to the database and issue the query. The original MySQL connector `mysql_*` is full of security issues, lacks prepared statements, is ripe for injection, and is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.

Here's an example alternative:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db;charset=UTF-8;", "my_user", "my_pass");

$statement = $pdo->query("SELECT some_field FROM some_table");

while( $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
    // .. do what you need to
```

Second, please use CSS to set the background colors. The bgcolor attribute is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.1).

Here's an example alternative:

```
$row_colour = (($row_count % 2) == 0) ? $colour_even: $colour_odd;
echo '
    <tr style="background-color: #' . $row_colour . ';">
        <td width="150">' . $row['FirstName'] . '</td>
        <td><a href="' . $row['LastName'] . '">' .$row['LastName'] . '</a></td>
     </tr>';
$row_count++;
```

Also, there is a syntax error because you're using `colour_even` and `colour_odd` as constants when you declared them as variables.

Lastly, using the `align` attributes in HTML is deprecated, too. Please consider using the CSS equivalent, `text-align: center`.

Comment: Thanks for tips. I will return rather old library book. It seemed OK as it matched quite a few similar examples on the web!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, PHP has a fairly low learning curve, so you can find examples that match nearly anything you search for. It's a great thing and it's a horrible thing. Keep trying though!