# While loop to switch between 2 values

Tags: php, html

I have a **PHP while loop** to loop out content on my site.

I'd like my HTML to appear like this:

```
<div style="background:red">
first box
</div>

<div style="background:blue">
second box
</div>

<div style="background:red">
third box
</div>
```

and so on.....so basically jump between either red or blue bgcolor.

How can do I do this with PHP?

My current code:

```
<?php

    if(get_field('toolkit_item')):

        $i = 0;

        while(the_repeater_field('toolkit_item')):

        ?>

        <div class="content-block">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="medium-12 columns">

                    <?php

                        $i++;
                        echo '<h1>';
                        echo $i.'. ';
                        echo get_sub_field('title'); 
                        echo '</h1>';

                        echo get_sub_field('text_block');

                    ?>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <?php

        endwhile; 

    endif;

    ?>
```

Comment: What does your while loop currently look like? Hard to give an answer without seeing what condition you're using; need PHP.

Comment: Seems like you might want to keep a tracker - either a boolean or an index (odd vs even)

Comment: Good call @MariM :-)

Comment: The usual approach here is to count with an integer (say, `$i`) while looping and check for `$i % 2 == 0` in each iteration (i.e., whether the counter is even).

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I have updated with my current PHP :)

Comment: This looks like WordPress with ACF repeaters, correct?

Comment: Sure is - love 'em :)

Comment: Though you asked for PHP, [it can be done with CSS alone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30171903/541091)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski is the best and correct answer even not php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30171903/5035890

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Add as an answer please namesake - want to green tick you for that genius :-D

Comment: @michaelmcgurk I'm going to mark this as a duplicate to the other, since it has both the `$i %2 == 0` and CSS examples as answers. It's not my work, and I'm not deserving of credit for it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That's a very good point.